# How to auto adjustment layout design in android

Tags: android, adjustment

I used 10 button in my screen, but some buttons was hiding covered by the screen. when i rotate the portrait shape some buttons was hidden, how to do. Please tell the solution

Comment: Search for "android handling rotation change"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support your application for both of `Portrait` and `Landscape` mode then you have to create separate layout to support tow different mode for your application.

Or, If you want to support your app only in `Portrait` mode then you can define it in your `Manifest` file as follows...

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Create design landscape and also portrait

1)you need create folder under res like this layout-land ----> under this folder u need use same file name "Sample.xml" u can able to handle landscape and portrait.